Optimal coding for uniform distribution
I'm following Elements of information theory by THOMAS M. COVER. The problem is about finding an optimal coding for uniform distribution. The reasoning from the solution manual works like this:
Firstly, it argues that the shortest and longest code-word must not be greater than $1$. This part perfectly makes sense. Then, it starts this confusing conclusion: Denote the difference between $n$, the number of samples to be coded, and the next smaller power of $2$ as
$$d = n - 2^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor}$$
It claims that there must exist $2d$ code-words of length $\lceil \log_{2}n \rceil$ and $n - 2d$ code-words of length $\lfloor \log_{2}n \rfloor$.
Why is this? It is true that $\lfloor \log_{2} n \rfloor$ must be achieved since we cannot code $n$ with less than that number of bits. But where does the $d$ come from?

the shortest and longest code-word must not be greater than $1$ doesn't make any sense to me - does it lack something like difference in length?

("Do the math" for $n = 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9$.)

@greybeard I did. It seems that my answer only provides intuition. I fail to make it rigorous. Any idea?

I'm lost: what has been the question, and what is your answer to it?

This is probably due to Huffman algorithm. Since all the probabilities are the same, the tree must be of the form of either a complete tree or a tree with leaves distancing no more than 1 level(consider $n = 4, 6, 7, 8$). The general formula would be $\lfloor \log_{2}n \rfloor$ for the "lower level" and $\lceil \log_{2}n \rceil$ for the "higher level". Note that "when we run" Huffman it means that we merge each pair first and build upwards. $2^{\lfloor \log_{2}n \rfloor + 1} - n$ of these go to the lower level and the rest go to the higher level.
